# api get route doesn't return anything

Tags: mongodb, get

I want to make a function that will return all my itineraries made by the same user.
I have the table: itinerary[name,startdate,enddate,userEmail,locationsid[] ].

```
exports.findAllByEmail = (req, res) => {
  const email=req.params.email;
    Itinerary.find({userEmail:req.params.userEmail})
    .then(data => {
      if (!data)
        res.status(404).send({ message: "Not found Itinerary with id " + userEmail });
      else res.send(data);
    })
      .catch(err => {
        res.status(500).send({
          message:
            err.message || "Some error occurred while retrieving tutorials."
        });
      });
  }
```

The route is correct, but it doesn't return anything.

Comment: when I do the same code but with id instead of email, it works perfectly

Comment: You are getting `email` like `const email=req.params.email;` but then find by `userEmail` like this `userEmail:req.params.userEmail`. If `req.params.userEmail` is `undefined` maybe is the problem why it is not return anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue you're facing might be due to a mismatch between the variable names in your code. In your function, you're using `req.params.email` to get the email value, but in the query, you're using `req.params.userEmail`

`Itinerary.find({ userEmail: email }) // Use 'email' instead of 'userEmail'`